# getting values and objects from jsp to Spring MVC controller and DB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on a  spring MVC application to learn spring. My users.jsp is:

```
<body>
<h1>Users</h1>
<form:form modelAttribute="user" method="GET" >
<table>
    <thead style="background: #fcf">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>User Id</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Role</th>               
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user">
        <tr>
            <td>${user.id}</td>
            <td>${user.name}</td>
            <td>${user.userId}</td>
            <td>${user.password}</td>
            <td>${user.email}</td>
            <td>${user.department}</td>
            <td>${user.role}</td>

    <td><a href="<c:url value='/user/edit/${user.id}' />">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="<c:url value='/user/delete/${user.id}' />">Delete</a></td>
    <td><a href="<c:url value='/user/update/${user.id}' />">Update</a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</form:form>
</body>
```

this fetches a list of all the users from the database.  I want to update the fields of user table. On clicking on a href Edit link the request goes to the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value=("/user/edit/{id}"),method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String editUse(@PathVariable(value="id") Integer id, Model         model) {              
            logger.info("Received request to updateRe person");     
    // Retrieve existing user by id and add to model
            model.addAttribute("userAttribute", userService.findById(id));  
// This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/editpage.jsp           
            return "editingUser";
        }
```

editingUser.jsp is:

```
<body>
    <h2>User Update</h2>
    <%=new java.util.Date()%>
    <p>You are Updating a user with id : ${userAttribute.id}</p>    
    <c:url var="saveUrl" value="/user/edit?id=${userAttribute.id}" />
    <form:form action="${saveUrl}" method="POST" modelAttribute="userAttribute">    
        <table>     
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="id">Id:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="id" disabled="true"/></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="name">Name:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="userId">User Id</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="userId"/></td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="email">Email</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="email"/></td>         
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="password">Password</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="password"/></td>          
        </tr>
    </table>    
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    </form:form>    
</body>
```

on clicking on submit button the control goes to

```
@RequestMapping(value=("/user/edit/{userAttribute.id}"), method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String editedUse(@ModelAttribute("userAttribute") User user, @RequestParam(value="id") Integer id,  Model model) {               
            logger.info("Received request to updateRe person");
                //reset the id
            user.setId(id);         
            // Delegate to userService for editing
            userService.update(user);           
            // Add id reference to the Model
            model.addAttribute("id", id);           
             model.addAttribute("user", user);
            return "editedUser";
        }
```

my ediedUser.jsp is

```
<body>
    <h1>Updated User</h1>
    <p>
        You have edited/updated  a user with id ${id} at
        <%=new java.util.Date()%></p>
    <h1>Persons</h1>
</body>
```

I get

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/UniProject08/user/edit] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'
```

also the data is not updated on my database

the userDaoImpl for updating/saving etc  is

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    // ***********************save User*****************
    @Transactional
    public boolean save(User user) {

        // Retrieve session from Hibernate
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        // save
        session.save(user);
        return true;
    }

    // **************update/edit******************

    @Transactional
    public User update(User user) {

        logger.info("Updating existing person");

        // Retrieve session from Hibernate
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        // Retrieve existing person via id

        User existingUser = (User) session.get(User.class, user.getId());

        // Assign updated values to this person
        existingUser.setName(user.getName());
        existingUser.setName(user.getUserId());
        existingUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        existingUser.setRole(user.getRole());
        existingUser.setDepartment(user.getDepartment());

        // update User
        session.update(existingUser);

        // return to jsp
        return existingUser;
    }

    // ***********find user by Id*************

    public User findById(int id) {

        // Retrieve session from Hibernate

        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        // get user
        User u = (User) session.get(User.class, new Integer(id));
        return u;
    }

    // *************************List of User**************

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public List<User> listPersons() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<User> personsList = session.createQuery("from User").list();
        for (User u : personsList) {
            logger.info("User List::" + u);
        }
        return personsList;
    }

    // *************************Delete a User**************
    public User deleteUser(int id) {            
        logger.info(" Delete a User");      
        // Retrieve session from Hibernate
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();      
         // Retrieve existing person first
        User u = (User) session.load(User.class, id);
        if(null != u) {
            session.delete(u);

logger.info("Person deleted successfully, person details=" + u);
        } else {

            logger.info("user is not deleted successfully, person details=" + u);
            }

        return u;
    }
```

Please suggest as I am stuck with @pathVariable and @requestParam i guess or something else is not right. Thanks